# Implement dependent lists while creating a component in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, schema, custom-url

Keyword pattern

```
A
    --A1
        --A11
            --A111
        --A12
        --A13
   --A2
   --A3

B
    --B1
        --B11
            --B111
        --B12
            --B121
```

In the schema I have an embedded schema with two fields.

```
1. main category that will prompt the user to select A, B or C
2. Sub category: It is custom URL field. It is multivalued.
```

When the user clicks to add value to Sub category, for the first time it takes the value of main category field and fetches its corresponding keywords. If the user has chosen A in main category, it will show A1, A2 and A3.

When the user again wants to add sub category to it,  it will get the value selected in its above field and displays its corresponding keywords.
If the user has chosen A1, then it shall display A11, A12 and A13.

And this goes on like this and user can add as many sub categories as he want.

I am not sure if we can implement this in Tridion.

I am not sure if Tridion provides out of Box technique to do this.

Do we have to implement custom URL for this.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to develop a GUI Extension, or as you mention, a custom URL for this.  Unfortunately there is no OOTB solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

Tridion has the Tree control to select Keywords.

Additionally you can write a small GUI extension that changes the Root Id that is passed as a query string when you open the Item Selector from the Tree control so that it will have the parent category / keyword you need in your hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely are going to need a UI extension. Take a look at my answer here on how to access dropdown fields in the Component View:

[How to populate the dropdown in component editing screen using anguilla framework?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3210/131)