# Can we model dependencies between lists of keywords in Tridion?

Tags: cme, keyword

I have the requirement to fetch the all the keywords inside the keyword using some event over component.

Say for example that I have one category called product pages. Inside this I have two keywords:

1. dispenser
2. consumable

now inside the each of above keyword I have different keywords like below:

1. dispenser

   1. hand towel
   2. paper roll
2. consumable

   1. skin care
   2. wash room

Now from above, my requirement is in the component first it should display dispenser and consumable in the drop down box, then after selecting one of it, it should display the keywords inside it like hand towel and paper roll if author select the dispenser.

Please let me know whether it is feasible in the Tridion or not?

Answer (score 4):

This question is very similar to this one : [Implement dependent lists while creating a component in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3236/implement-dependent-lists-while-creating-a-component-in-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1)

Your options are

- write a custom GUI extension, or a custom url
- use the tree keyword selector (this one is easiest to implement, and is standard tridion functionality)

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, shouldn't we close it as such?