# Is there a field change event I can subscribe to?

Tags: event-system, web8.5, custom-url

I am working on a customization where we want to update `field2` when a value is selected in `field1`. `Field1` is a component link field and `field2` will have template dropdown based on `field1` component schema.
I am thinking to use event system but I can not find a field change event which I can subscribe to. Is there any?
If there isn't such event which I can subscribe to then I guess I will have to use custom URL for `field2`. Are there any other options than custom URL which will be fit here?

Comment: You have tagged your question with event-system (.NET event handlers) and custom-url, but reading the description I think it is more about UI extensions on the CME. Maybe you can **edit** your question and provide a bit more detail about what type of customizxation you are working on, so you will be able to get better answers.

Comment: Yes @BartKoopman, a UI extension will also work.

Answer (score 8):

You could consider ***[[removed:OOTB]]* Supported category use with the Tree View.** The user would select from the top-down and the field populated with the final select.

Of course, by *supported* I mean without having to provide a custom extension - to add them is a content job; you could initially do this as a manual process and then automate the creation/update of schema/templates later).

If you wanted to remove the manual effort of managing the keywords - you could query the core service to map these relationships and populate the drop-down lists automagically. With the exception of your custom extension directly, this (the management of your selections) would still be considered *supported* as you're not extending anything in the context of managing keywords - and in terms of the custom GUI extension, you're simply using the APIs and general frameworks provided.

Of course, you could manage a mapping file as a deployed file if you chose - but this at the cost of maintenance and deployment (even for a template name change) - I would look to manage the values/relationships through the API or content editors as much as possible.

Two points (if you use Categories/Keywords):

- Be wary of duplicated IDs (say, you had London in CA and UK - I'd use the IDs caLon and ukLon etc.)
- Accepting the requirement may include "leaving the Country/State visible also" - which wouldn't be OOTB - then I expect your GUI extension would be much simpler by way of simply parsing the category/abstract keyword/keyword selection and putting to the screen.

Of course, you could **go all out** *Full Metal Jacket* on this - here you'd take the approach documented by Jamie - [How to populate the dropdown in component editing screen using anguilla framework?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3207/how-to-populate-the-dropdown-in-component-editing-screen-using-anguilla-framewor)

Comment: I do not have templates as keywords so I cant use the OOTB category with the Tree View.

Comment: Updating the keywords would still mean you're providing a _supported_ (as opposed to OOTB) solution which is usually the first approach to explore.

Comment: @RakeshChoudhary - did you get a way forward for this? What was it?

Comment: Still deciding but looks like I will go with GUI extension with Anguilla Framework.

Answer (score -1):

There is no event for Field Change. You need to have a custom URL only, in order to select a value in `field2` based on the value selected in `field1`.